# What amp rating of 24VAC transformer for LM317T?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, amperage

I want to know what size transformer for LM317 at full 30 VDC. I know it's a 24VAC center-tapped transformer but is a 1A or a 5A transformer best suited for a linear power supply of 1.5-30 VDC?

I will be using a standard LM317 variable power supply circuit with a 2200μF 50V smoothing capacitor and a 240Ω drain resistor and potentiometer. I have a homemade oversized aluminum heatsink that is quite large.

[image]

Comment: You are confused about voltage and current.  The LM317 will draw as much current as it needs to supply current to the load.  If the load doesn't pull much current, you won't need to deliver much to the LM317.

Comment: This project is likely to be disappointing overall; if you attempt it, do it for the *learning experience* not the utility of the result.

Comment: Care to inlighten mew as to why or just form unjust opinions

Comment: @user646333 What is your goal with this project?  How much current do you need to source at, say, 1.5 V?

Comment: The circuit you show uses a non-center-tapped transformer - the secondary only has two connections.

Answer (score 2):

You first have to figure out the maximum output DC current of your power supply. This can be determined by your load, by the maximum current handling capacity of your regulator or diodes, or (most likely the case) by the maximum power dissipation at your regulator.

Once you know the maximum DC current, you have to determine what will be the RMS current at the transformer's secondary windings. This is actually more complicated than what it seems  because the current waveform at the transformer is not trivial - the current only flows through the windings of the transformer when the voltage is higher than the capacitor voltage plus the voltage drop across the diodes.

I'll give you two choices at this point. If you're really enthusiastic about it and want to know more than 99% of the linear supply designers, I encourage you to simulate the circuit and calculate the worst case RMS current (square root of average squared current) of the transformer for your case. If you just want a quick answer, a good rule of thumb to use for the rms current at the secondary is (see reference below):

for center tap secondary with 2 diodes: \$I_{rms} = 1.2  I_{DC}\$

for 2-wire secondary with 4 diodes: \$I_{rms} = 1.8  I_{DC}\$

Keep in mind that the current at the primary of the transformer will be the current at the secondary multiplied by the inverse of the voltage ratio of your transformer (well, there is also magnetization current at play, but we don't need to get there). For example, if the primary voltage is 10x the secondary voltage, then the primary current will be 1/10 of the secondary current.

P.S.: I recommend you take a look at https://www.smcelectronics.com/DOWNLOADS/1980-VOLTREG.PDF, chapter 8 starting at page 74. Don't be impressed by the age of the document: linear power supply design is an old and almost forgotten art and therefore relies on almost forgotten references. :^)

Answer (score 0):

Four issues.

1. The 1N4007 diode is rated for 1 A continuous operation.  If you expect to have output currents greater than this, you should change to diodes rated for 3 A.
2. The LM317 T is rated for 1.5 A continuous output current.  With a 5 A transformer, there is a real possibility that an incorrect load can draw much more than this, causing the 317 to go into either overcurrent or over-temperature protection.  While the part probably will survive this a few times, it is a significant over-stress of the chip and should be avoided.  With a 1 A transformer, high output currents still are possible.  However, the transformer size will limit the total energy.
3. A 24 Vac source has a peak value of 33.94 V.  With the bridge arrangement, two diodes are conducting at any given point in time.  If we assume 0.8 V Vf for each diode, that subtracts 1.6 V from the peak voltage across the filter capacitor C1, reducing it to 32.34 V  The LM317 has a rated input-output differential voltage (dropout voltage) of 2.3 V (reading a chart on the datasheet).  This reduces the maximum possible output voltage to 30.04 V.  This is uncomfortably close to your requirement of 30 V, and is possible only at very low output currents that minimize filter capacitor ripple voltage.  Which leads to  . . .
4. Filter capacitor C1 is too small.  Assuming a 60 Hz power line frequency, the period between voltage peaks across C1 is 8.33 ms.  Using the constant current discharge equation for a capacitor (because the output current into the load is a constant, even though the voltage across the capacitor is changing):

E x C = i x t

Voltage decrease times capacitance value equals the constant discharge current times the time period.  Rearranging:

E = (i x t) / C  ==  (1.5 x 0.00833) / 0.0022 F = 5.682 V

IOW with a filter capacitor of 2200 uF and an output current of 1.5 A, the peak-to-peak ripple voltage (the voltage sag) across the filter capacitor will be almost 5.7 V.  This reduces the maximum possible clean, regulated output voltage to 26.6 V.  At higher output voltages, 120 Hz ripple will be present on the output.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your load will be 240 Ω worst-case:

Calculate how much current you intend to draw.

$$\frac{30 V}{240 Ω} = 0.125 A$$

That is how much current you can expect the secondary to carry.  Add a little bit for safety.

The primary current will be much less, so you shouldn't need to worry about it.

EDIT:  I will leave the above as a simple example of using Ohm's Law to calculate current.

Now that I have seen your schematic I realize that your load is in fact not 240 Ω.  Unless you are otherwise limiting your load, you should accommodate the full 2 A that the LM317 can draw.

If you are indeed limited to a choice between a 1 A and a 5 A transformer, go with the 5 A.

Comment: The problem is the original description of 240 ohms as a "load" resistor. Reference to the circuit shows it is the drain resistor (from output to reference) for the LM317. The actual load is unspecified. Consequently, the transformer should be capable of supplying the LM317 maximum load current, or around 2A.

Comment: @henros Ah, good point!  That schematic wasn't posted when I wrote this answer.  I will adjust my answer.

Comment: Somehow got off subject in another thread about the same thing. I will post the schematic again at the end.  I have a 0-30vdc 5 amp variable workbench power supply. I am trying to mimic that in a linear power supply.  30v 5 amp max. using lm317t if possible otherwise I will make a 1.5 amp max.

Comment: https://electrosome.com/variable-power-supply-lm317-voltage-regulator/

Comment: I also mentioned in the other thread that i already have a transformer i purchased by accident that is not center tapped rather only two wires green and red on secondary.  240/208/120vac primary  and 24vac secondary 50/60 hz 40va

Comment: evildemonic I apologize for my typos

Comment: @user646333 Ok, you will not be able to get 5 A out of an LM317.  Even at 1.5 A, you will be dissipating a lot of heat in the LM317 at low voltages.

Comment: With 30 V input, and 1.5 V output, you are dropping 28.5 V across the regulator.  At 1.5 A that is over 40 watts!

Comment: If you really want to build your own linear supply with these specs, you should use some huge output transistors and a very large heat sink.  Also, seriously consider a multi-tap transformer so you can select different input voltages to your regulator for different voltage ranges.

Comment: Thanks for the random downvote with no comment...super helpful